# Для чего нужен Тип в elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Читаю книгу по elasticsearch, и не понимаю, для чего у индексов создавать тип? Если с 6 версии es, у индекса может быть только один тип.
В книге написано, что это нужно для логического разделения.
Разделения чего? Почему индекса недостаточно?

Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Индекс - это бд, тип - таблица. Примерно так

Comment: В бд может быть множество таблиц, а в индексе только один тип.

Answer (score 0):

Документация [гласит](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html):

> Initially, we spoke about an
>   “index” being similar to a “database” in an SQL database, and a “type”
>   being equivalent to a “table”.
>
> This was a bad analogy that led to incorrect assumptions. In an SQL
>   database, tables are independent of each other. The columns in one
>   table have no bearing on columns with the same name in another table.
>   This is not the case for fields in a mapping type.
>
> In an Elasticsearch index, fields that have the same name in different
>   mapping types are backed by the same Lucene field internally. In other
>   words, using the example above, the user_name field in the user type
>   is stored in exactly the same field as the user_name field in the
>   tweet type, and both user_name fields must have the same mapping
>   (definition) in both types.
>
> This can lead to frustration when, for example, you want deleted to be
>   a date field in one type and a boolean field in another type in the
>   same index.
>
> On top of that, storing different entities that have few or no fields
>   in common in the same index leads to sparse data and interferes with
>   Lucene’s ability to compress documents efficiently.
>
> For these reasons, we have decided to remove the concept of mapping
>   types from Elasticsearch.

Иными словами, имея несколько разных полей с одинаковым названием, но хранящимися в разных типах вы можете столкнуться с проблемой, когда захотите удалить это поле.

Answer (score 0):

Индекс — это контейнер, который в Elasticsearch хранит документы одного типа и управляет ими. Тип в Elasticsearch соответствует таблице, а документ — записи в ней. Только надо понимать, что это всего лишь абстракция.

Отличие состоит в том, что в структуре реляционных баз данных почти всегда содержится несколько таблиц, а индекс может содержать только один тип.

Документ состоит из нескольких полей и является базовой единицей информации, хранимой в Elasticsearch. Документы содержат несколько полей, например, поля sku, title, description, price и др. Каждое поле и его значение можно увидеть как пару «ключ — значение» в документе, где ключ — это имя поля, а значение — значение поля.

Answer (score 0):

Сравнение понятий Elasticsearch с SQL не очень корректное. Лучше сразу понять, что индекс - это склад документов и для быстрого поиска по нему, не нужно пытаться выстраивать связи между документами, лучше, чтоб наоборот, данные были как можно более денормализованы.

> Sometimes the best option is to simply denormalize your data where appropriate. The relational facilities that Elasticsearch provides are great for certain scenarios...but were never meant to provide the robust relational features that you expect from an RDBM.
>
> At it's heart, Elasticsearch is a flat hierarchy and trying to force relational data into it can be very challenging. Sometimes the best solution is to judiciously choose which data to denormalize, and where a second query to retrieve children is acceptable. Denormalization gives you arguably the most power and flexibility.
>
> Of course, this comes with the burden of administrative overhead. You get to manage relations, and you get to perform the required queries/filters to associate the various types. Yay!

Вот статья разработчиков Elasticsearch об удалении типов - https://www.elastic.co/blog/moving-from-types-to-typeless-apis-in-elasticsearch-7-0
В поисковом индексе они не так и нужны, тем более, если нужно установить связи в одном индексе, можно использовать тип nested или parent/child. Но стоит понимать, что использование этих типов при большом количестве данных в индексе, значительно ухудшает производительность поиска и ранжирования(особенно если оно кастомное).